# VS 2019 : No repository available on TFS 2019 installed on local network server

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-devops-server-2019

I have TFS 2019 installed on a server in our local network. There is a project and a repository there but while I connect to server, there is no repository available there with a yellow rectangle.

[image]

I have signed out from my Microsoft account because it is On-Premise local version but it didn't help.

This is the project and repository on my TFS server. There is no file there because I want to push my project's file for the first time.

[image]

How do I know what is the problem showing project and repositories on TFS in vs 2019 while there is no error messages during connecting to TFS server?

As a point my account is administrator in VS 2019 either in TFS 2019.

Comment: Did you add yourself to the members of this project ?

Comment: @Afshin, yes I have created the project in tfs myself

Comment: Firstly, you should create collection and create repository under that collection. Did you do that ?

Comment: @Afshin, yes, in the second image I have attached you can see the collection and the project and the repository are created.

Comment: Did you login to windows with the same account ? you should logged in to windows or tfs team explorer in vs when trying to connect to team explorer and see collection.

Comment: @Afshin, I have logged in to TFS and Windows with same account